# What visa do I need for a stopover in Amsterdam?

Tags: visas, schengen, customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, ams

I am travelling from London to Bangalore, with a layover in Amsterdam of 23 hours. What visa or permission do I need to get so I can use this time to roam around Amsterdam?

I am a citizen of India and I have a UK visa.

Comment: You need an EU visa for sure :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need a short-stay (C Type) Schengen visa. In the application form, select transit as the travel purpose if it's an option.